# Is there a way to send push-notifications via adb shell or mock one for tests?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, adb

I'm trying to test the notifications of my android app. Is there a way to mock a Firebase notification or send one via adb?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.